# Meat and wine on Chol HaMoed

Tags: eating, chol-hamoed, simchah-joy-happiness

There is an obligation for men to [eat meat and drink wine on each day of Chol HaMoed](http://www.torahmusings.com/2015/04/chol-hamoed-meat-wine-and-clothing/), assuming one normally enjoys their consumption. I have three questions regarding this obligation:

1. May one fulfill this obligation at night or only during the day? Why or why not?
2. Does this obligation follow the particular details of other eating and drinking obligations? For instance, must one have a *rivi'is* of wine within *kdei shtiyas rivi'is*, and a *kezayis* of meat within *kdei achilas pras*?
3. Must the meat and wine be consumed together in one sitting, or can they be consumed separately at different times throughout the day?

Sources or convincing arguments appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39522/discussion-on-question-by-y-isseroff-meat-and-wine-on-chol-hamoed).

Comment: -1 for a poorly-worded question. ❧ Your source says nothing about being _obligated_ to eat meat. All it says is: "One should ... make an effort to eat meat every day of Chol Hamoed." ❧ Please: [Edit] your post. Make your words better match your source, or cite a source which better matches your words. ❧ Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's best to consume wine together with slow-digesting proteins or fats (e.g. meat, fish, nuts, or legumes), instead of with a quick-digesting meal (e.g. a jam sandwich) or on an empty stomach. Alcohol is somewhat toxic to the brain, liver, and pancreas; if the wine reaches your intestines too quickly, this toxicity may be magnified.

Answer (score 4):

*Nemukei Orach Chaim* 529:2 writes that one should have a [*revi'is*](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/much-wine-one-need-havdalah/) of wine. *Hilchot Chol HaMoed Zichron Shlomo* (page 3; based on *Sh”t Rosh* 25:1), on the other hand, writes that a [*melo lugmav*](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/much-wine-one-need-havdalah/) is sufficient.

Regarding your third question: My intuition tells me that separate times are definitely not a problem.

See http://dinonline.org/2016/04/28/drinking-wine-on-chol-hamoed/ for the pace at which the wine should be drunk.

See also http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=2162.

Some authorities maintain that, at every meal eaten on Chol HaMoed, wine must be drunk. (See *Emes L'Yaakov* by Rabbi Yaakov Kamenetsky, siman 530, footnote 483.)